# Unable to dynamically add jump list tasks to IE9 / Win7 menu

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, jump-list

I am able to add "tasks" to a pinned site in IE9 using meta tags eg.

```
<meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Twitter;action-uri=http://www.twitter.com;icon-uri=http://a1.twimg.com/a/1301438647/images/favicon.ico" />
```

But if I try to add new tasks using javascript, they never show up.

```
function jQuery_ActivateJumplists() {
    var favicon = "http://a1.twimg.com/a/1301438647/images/favicon.ico";
    var externalWindow = null;

    if (window.external.msIsSiteMode()) {
        externalWindow = window.external;
        externalWindow.msSiteModeCreateJumpList("Twitter!");
        externalWindow.msSiteModeAddJumpListItem("Twitter Link", "http://www.twitter.com", favicon);
        externalWindow.msSiteModeShowJumplist();
    }
};
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you debugged this to see whether the code inside the if is ever reached?

Comment: Yes, no JS errors. I put a log at the end inside the if{} and it is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to have been an issue with corrupt cache in windows.
Solution is to create and run a .bat with the following contents...

```
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\*
del /F /Q %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\*
```